# How to use real Air Simulation?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, ocean-simulation

i found few tutorials about blender simulation but it doesn't include air temperature and humidity. It has some flow but i can't tell if it's realistic or not.

I don't know if i should use, Flow Design from Autodesk or if blender can do it also?

Comment: Blender's physics do not produce accurate simulations, only artistic ones. Wind effector only has turbulence and the smoke simulator only has heat.